# How to get new edit Text on Enter Key pressed event in Dialogbox using Android programing? Can you provide sample code for that?

Tags: android-edittext, android-dialogfragment

I had tried through below code but not getting key event.

```
editText1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){

    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
        if((event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)&&(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
        {
            editText1.clearFocus();
            editText2.requestFocus();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `event.getKeyCode()` instead of just `keyCode`

```
editText1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){

    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
        if((event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)&&(event.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
        {
            editText1.clearFocus();
            editText2.requestFocus();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Textwatcher instead:
try this

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (s.length()>0 && s.subSequence(s.length()-1, s.length()).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("\n"))
             {
                editText1.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL));
                editText1.clearFocus();
                editText2.requestFocus();
             }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This code is for getting focus on another edit-text. But what i need is new edit text on enter or any other key press event.

Comment: The code which you posted in the question also is requesting focus to another edit-text. New edit text in the sense what? Do you want to create new edit text programmatically when enter or other key is pressed?